# Optimizer supporting `or` and `count` constraints in AMPL

Tags: optimization, solver, ampl

I have designed an AMPL model.

I want to add to it some constraints such as:

```
s.t. Max_dif_prod {t in 1..T}: 
    count {p in PRODUCTS} (production[p,t] > 0) <= max_dif_prod ;

s.t. Min_prod {p in PRODUCTS, t in 1..T}:
    production[p,t] = 0 or production[p,t] >= min_production[p] ;
```

But neither the default solver (MINOS) nor the open source non linear solvers listed in the AMPL webpage (IPOPT, BONMIN and COUENNE) seem to be able to handle this type of constraints, and since I am in a demo version the proprietary AMPL non linear solvers are out of the question.

What solver can I use instead if I want these kind of restrictions? Or how can I substitute them by restrictions that any of the solvers I mentioned above may be able to solve?

Comment: Well... what document is your model based on? What does it tell you which solvers are supported? Without AMPL exp, a quick search makes me think `or` and co is reserved to CP solvers and CPLEX. You can always do a MIP-based formulation yourself. Grab any book on integer-programming or start with [AIMMS Modeling Guide](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_IntegerProgrammingTricks.pdf). `production[p,t] = 0 or production[p,t] >= min_production[p]` is simply an indicator-formulation for the rhs or and then `(1-production[p,t]) + indicator >= 1` (assuming prod is bin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [chapter about integer programming](https://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/23-integer.pdf) in the AMPL book has helped me solve this question.

The solution I implemented was to reformulate the restrictions using binary variables and then use the CPLEX solver.